# Output of drop down list in php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, drop-down-menu

I want the output of "cor_resp_template" where is nome and select that values for in next page do some operations like(sum, multiplication,...). I try the first time use JavaScript, but i don´t know if the code is correct. I try to analysis step by step and seems ok for that operation.

In next picture like you see the empty values. Don´t show the table with the values for after submit that values for next page.

[image: Output in the page.]

The output of database of the table template where is all the values:

[image]

That is the output of that page:

http://localhost/dissertacao/conceptualization13.php?menuId=1

After we have the code where we use the JavaScript for get the values in next page where is the PHP query.

```
 <script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("$option").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("$option").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","template1.php?option="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<?php
echo "<select name='template' class='form-control' onchange='showUser(this.value)'>";
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("teste") or die(mysql_error()); // selecciona a database do server escolhido
echo "<center>";

               // Get the county names from database - no duplicates
               $query = "SELECT DISTINCT nome FROM template";
{
       // execute the query, $result will hold all of the Counties in an array
       $resultado = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
           $option .="<option>" . $row['nome'] . "</option>";
           echo $option;
       }
   echo "</select>";
echo "<br>";
?>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>
<div id="valores"><b>Os valores para este template são:</b></div>
```

template1.php

The following code is the PHP QUERY where is called for give the output of the table with the values where is nome in the SQL table.

```
 <?php
    $option = (isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '');
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("teste") or die(mysql_error()); // selecciona a database do server escolhido
    $query="SELECT * FROM template WHERE 'nome' = '".$option."'";
    $resultado = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Valores</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {

        var_dump ($resultado);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['corp_resp_template'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>**
```

Comment: You should probably post the result in your question as well because we can't see it since the URL `http://localhost/dissertacao/....` only works on your system.

Comment: `var_dump ($resultado);` gets sent in the response as well, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The output, where is given the distinct names:string(105) "testeferrariteslaola  and the output of var_dump($resultado) is not showing and try the value of the POST and it is the same. It seems are no connection between the 2 pages.

Comment: `$option` is an invalid HTML `id` value. Are you sure that is the actual `id` of the element ? I'm referring to the `document.getElementById("$option")` call.

Comment: I check in the forum`s the value of the getElementById can get, can be string or variable too. But is the first time i use that i don´t know if is correct.

Comment: Hello, i test the query one by one in each page. The problem seems is in the JavaScript, What i can check?